# CSS Nav pushes right in IE 7

Tags: css, nav

Can someone help me trouble shoot this nav in IE7?  It jams right and I can't figure this darn problem out.  http://brccycling.com/2011/

Thanks,

Comment: I'm getting the following javascript error, I'm not sure whether it is involved in the menu, but it might: `Line: 332 Error: 'theme' is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to redo how you're placing the menu to a technique which will work between IE7/8 and other browsers such as Firefox:

- On `#top`, add `position: relative`.
- On `#nav`:

  - Remove `float: left`, because it's unneeded.
  - Remove the `margin` rule.
  - To replace what the `margin` was doing, add `top: 260px`, and `left: 290px`.

The technique we're now using (properly) is detailed here:

- http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/
- http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/